# Scala Data Type

Tags: scala, typing

As part of trying to understand the differences and similarities of scala, I'm trying to understand what the equivalent of the Java "Object" type.

If I had a Scala list List[TYPE], what would Type have to be to support any of the following
Int, Any, (Int, Any)).

Note: I understand this is bad (terrible) programming technique, but its to help my understanding.

I had initially thought that List[Any] would work, but couldn't get it to work for all cases:

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, ?)]
```

Similarly

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, (Any, Any))] [error] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any] [error] Note: (Any, (Any, Any)) <: Any, but class RDD is invariant in type T.
```

If Any is a super type of everything, why the mention of invariant here?

Comment: [A list of `Any`](http://lmazy.verrech.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/scala_type_hierarchy.png)

Answer (score 3):

You're right `Any` is a super type of all types in Scala.

The error messages are caused by different problems.

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, ?)]
```

In this case you have mixed subtype with supertype. The error states that you've used `Any` instead of `(Any, ?)`, only the other way around is allowed.

```
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Any, (Any, Any))] [error] required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any] [error] Note: (Any, (Any, Any)) <: Any, but class RDD is invariant in type T.
```

Here the problem is with polymorphism and variance annotations. If a type variable is invariant (neither covariant nor contravariant) the type must be an exact match. You can't use a sub or super type instead.

#### Covariance

To allow your second use case,  the type parameter in `RDD` should be covariant. Covariance in Scala is annotated with `+` (e.g. `class RDD[+T]`).

Covariance means that if a type `A` is a subtype of `B` and `Foo` is covariant in it's first type parameter, then `Foo[A]` is a subtype of `Foo[B]`.

Scala `<:` is used to describe an order (sub/super type relationship) between types.

```
(Any, (Any, Any)) <: Any
```

Means that `(Any, (Any, Any))` is a subtype of `Any`, but `RDD` is not covariant therefore `RDD[(Any, (Any, Any))] <: RDD[Any]` is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use scala console and type inference to check what type you will have:

```
scala> val list = List(1, (2, "String"), Array.empty[Byte])
list: List[Any] = List(1, (2,String), Array())
```

List[Any] is correct type